# send data from bpmn to java class

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I want get data from bpmn in java class. my code is :

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("s", s);     
    params.put("p", s);
    params.put("result", result);
    ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn");
    // check whether the process instance has completed successfully
    assertProcessInstanceCompleted(processInstance.getId(), ksession);
    assertNodeTriggered(processInstance.getId(), "Script Task 1");
```

I sent Variable "result" to bpmn and in bpmn Changes "result". now I want get value Modified "result" in java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice example how to do this in the [jBPM documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMBPMN2.html#d0e3387). You just need to cast your processInstance variable to WorkflowProcessInstance:

```
result = ((WorkflowProcessInstance) processInstance).getVariable("result");
```